# Regex to search for a phrase

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Hy,

please help me with a Regex to find phrases in a text.

My Regex is not ok. My assumption that phrases begin with uppercase and end with an dot, and between can contain anything.

```
\b([A-Z]+[aA-zZ]*\b(.)+)
```

Sincerly,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following if your between phrase doesn't also consist of a dot.

```
[A-Z][^.]*\.
```

Or perhaps, you could try using the following.

```
[A-Z].*?\.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one variant

```
\b([A-Z][^.]*\.+)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it starts with a Capital letter, end with a dot, zero or more anything in between them:

```
^[A-Z].*[.]$
```